# На это ушло полчаса. На что ушли эти полчаса?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, согласование, единственное-множественное-число

*На это **ушло** полчаса*. **Ушло**. **Это**. Это полчаса — не звучит. Тогда что "это"? Время? На это ушло время. Сколько? Полчаса.

*На что **ушли** эти полчаса*? **Ушли**. **Эти**. Эти полчаса — звучит. *Почему полчаса — **эти**?* Потому что 30 минут? На что ушли эти минуты? И сколько? 30 минут.

Какое правильное объяснение?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При подлежащем, выраженном сложным существительным, первую часть которого образует числительное *пол-*, (*полчаса, полкомнаты*) сказуемое ставится в форме единственного числа, а в прошедшем времени — в среднем роде, например: *Полмесяца пролетело быстро; Полдома сгорело.*

Но если при этих словах имеется **определение** в форме именительного падежа множественного числа, то и сказуемое ставится во множественном числе, например: ***Первые полчаса прошли незаметно**; Остальные полдома уцелели от пожара.*

Правильно:
*На что **ушло полчаса**? На чтение ушло полчаса.* [ед. ч., ср. род]
*На что **ушли** эти полчаса? **Эти полчаса** ушли на чтение.* [с определением; мн. ч.]

На выяснение этого **уходит полчаса**. Потом все обнимаются. [Андрей Колесников. Дальнобойщики // «Столица», 1997.09.29]
Встретила она меня как постороннего, и мне **потребовалось полчаса**, чтобы снова завоевать ее сердце. [К. И. Чуковский. Дневник (1953)]
**Оставались последние полчаса** безмятежной жизни на земле. [Валерий Аграновский. Вторая древнейшая. Беседы о журналистике (1976-1999)]

[ЭТОТ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82), **эти**, этих; *мн.* — местоименное прилагательное (то есть местоимение, совпадающее по синтаксической функции с прилагательным).
[**полчаса**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0)
Половина часа, **тридцать минут**. *Часы бьют каждые полчаса. Эти полчаса — решающие. Встретимся через полчаса. Прошло, прошли полчаса. Отсчитали последние полчаса.*

[Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим](http://journal.pushkin.institute/archive/archive/1977/77-06/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC.pdf) (Д. Э. Розенталь. М. А. Теленкова)

**Дополнение**
[Вопрос № 276294](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0)
При наличии определения здесь нормальна форма мн. ч.: *Прошли долгие полгода.* Определяющее прилагательное или причастие при словах типа ***полчаса**, полверсты, полжизни* **всегда** получает форму мн. ч.: *томительные полчаса, последние полверсты, прожитые полжизни.*
«Эти особенности определяются сосуществованием в сложных словах с *пол-* признаков слова и словосочетания с числительными типа *два часа, три ведра, две дюжины*» – пишут авторы «Русской грамматики» (М., 1980).

Comment: Ни *** не понятно, но очень интересно.

Answer (score 1):

> ***На это ушло полчаса.*** Ушло. Это. Это полчаса - не звучит. Тогда что "это"?

«Это» здесь – субстантивированное местоимение, **вмещающее содержание препозитивных контекстных предложений.** В данном предложении занимает позицию дополнения: ***ушло полчаса*** (на что?) – ***на это.***

Ну а контекст мог бы быть примерно таким:

***Он стал вкладывать листы в конверты, надписывать их…** ― и **на это** ушло еще полчаса.* [Дина Рубина. Белая голубка Кордовы (2008-2009)]

Answer (score 0):

Существительные со значением определенного и неопределенного количества, а также слова с первой частью **пол-** (**полчаса**, полгода) **обычно** требуют постановки сказуемого **в форму единственного числа**: *Пара ботинок была куплена за бесценок. Уйма времени ушла впустую. Масса ненужных вещей захламила квартиру.* ***Полчаса прошло незаметно*** (**но** с определением: ***Первые полчаса прошли незаметно***).
[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo)

Так что лучше сказать:

***На это ушло полчаса.***

Ср.: ***На это ушли драгоценные полчаса***.